# Kotlin: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:

Tags: kotlin

Getting the below error while compiling the kotlin project. Can someone help me understand the issue and how to fix it?

Kotlin: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
class org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException, unresolved supertypes: javax.servlet.ServletException
class org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException, unresolved supertypes: javax.servlet.ServletException
Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you probably need to add the `javax.servlet-api` dependency as a dependency, perhaps as `compileOnly` (Gradle) or `provided` (Maven).

The long answer depends on your specific project and how it's set up. Are you using Spring Boot? Are you packaging your application as a `.war` file or with an embedded server? What dependencies do you define?

I would only expect to see this error if you're packaging your application without an embedded server and there are some missing compile-time dependencies corresponding to the server APIs that will be provided by the servlet container at runtime.